# didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge delegate not getting called in Swift

Tags: swift

I am trying a sample project with NSURLConnection.

```
 import Foundation
 import UIKit
    class loginVC: ViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, NSURLConnectionDelegate, NSURLConnectionDataDelegate{
        var webData: NSMutableData!

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            webData = NSMutableData()
            callWebService("testdentist@gmail.com", Password:"1")

        }

        func callWebService(userName:NSString, Password:NSString){

            var strURl: NSURL = NSURL .URLWithString("")
            var request: NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: strURl, cachePolicy:NSURLRequestCachePolicy.ReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData, timeoutInterval:60.0)
            var postString: NSString = ""
            postString = postString.stringByAppendingFormat("username=%@&password=%@", userName,Password)
            request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            request.HTTPMethod = ""
            var connection: NSURLConnection = NSURLConnection(request: request, delegate:self)
            connection.start()
        }

        //NSURLConnection webservice
        func connection(connection: NSURLConnection!, didReceiveResponse response: NSURLResponse!){
           // webData.length = 0
            println("response")
        }

        func connection(connection: NSURLConnection!, didReceiveData data: NSData!){
           println(data.length)
            webData .appendData(data)
        }

        func connection(connection: NSURLConnection, didFailWithError error: NSError!){
            println("error in connection")
        }

        func connectionDidFinishLoading(connection: NSURLConnection!){

            var response: NSString = NSString(data: webData, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)

            println("response:\(response)")
            if response != ""{

            }

        }
        func connection(connection: NSURLConnection, didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge challenge: NSURLAuthenticationChallenge!){
            var authentication: NSURLCredential = NSURLCredential.credentialWithUser("", password:"", persistence: NSURLCredentialPersistence.ForSession)
        }  
    }
```

It seems all delegates are getting called except didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge delegate method.What i am missing.any help will be appreciated.thanks in advance

Comment: You don't need to call start() on the connection -- `start()` is only needed if usign `initWithRequest:delegate:startImmediately:` and passing false to startImmediately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For iOS 8 and above, you must implement [`connection(_:willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge:)`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLConnectionDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSURLConnectionDelegate/connection:willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge:). `connection:didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:` is not called in iOS8, only in older operating systems.

So, to provide authentication in iOS8 and above, implement the method above and in there you must invoke one of the challenge-responder methods (`NSURLAuthenticationChallengeSender protocol`):

```
useCredential:forAuthenticationChallenge:

continueWithoutCredentialForAuthenticationChallenge: 

cancelAuthenticationChallenge:

performDefaultHandlingForAuthenticationChallenge: 

rejectProtectionSpaceAndContinueWithChallenge:
```

`didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge` is a method on [`NSURLConnectionDelegate`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLConnectionDelegate_Protocol/), whilst the rest of your methods (except `didFailWithError`) are all [`NSURLConnectionDataDelegate`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLConnectionDataDelegate_protocol/) methods. Are you implementing both protocols in your controller? It would perhaps help if you posted all your class' code.

Comment: I have implemented both protocols.still it is not getting called?

Comment: What is your deployment target? iOS8 only?  `didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge` has been deprecated in iOS8.

Comment: what is the other way to do authentication?

Comment: See my edit - you must implement `connection(_:willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge:)` and in there you must invoke one of the challenge-responder methods (`NSURLAuthenticationChallengeSender` protocol):

`useCredential:forAuthenticationChallenge:`

`continueWithoutCredentialForAuthenticationChallenge:`

cancelAuthenticationChallenge:

`performDefaultHandlingForAuthenticationChallenge:`

`rejectProtectionSpaceAndContinueWithChallenge:`

Comment: I am getting error as 'loginVC' does not conform to protocol 'NSURLAuthenticationChallengeSender' when i add that protocol

Answer (score 0):

i don't think the question is in those terms for new Swift 3.0..

I have a similar problem, a code regularly working under xcode7/ios7-8-9/Swift 2.2

Migration have produced:

```
 func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, didReceive challenge: URLAuthenticationChallenge, completionHandler: (Foundation.URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition, URLCredential?) -> Void) {
```

...
}

but does NOT work.

rewrite by hand:

```
func urlSession(_: URLSession,
                didReceive challenge: URLAuthenticationChallenge,
                completionHandler: @escaping (URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition, URLCredential?) -> Void) {


}
```

now it DOES work.
my two cents.